# shell script to create azure service principal using certificate

Tags: azure, shell, service-principal

I am trying to create service principal with certificate authentication using shell script. Please guide, I have spent numerous hours on it and I am no way near.
I have the following snippet that works for rbac and through password, instead i need to create service principal with certificate authentication.

$(az account set --subscription $1)
$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name nameSP --)

Comment: `az ad sp create-for-rbac -h`

Answer (score 1):

I found the following examples [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac):

**Create using a self-signed certificate:**

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --create-cert
```

**Create using a self-signed certificate, and store it within KeyVault:**

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --keyvault MyVault --cert CertName --create-cert
```

**Create using existing certificate in KeyVault:**

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --keyvault MyVault --cert CertName
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gaurav.
There are two ways to use the cert, one is you create yourself and the other is you get it from azure, by using the following code snippet.
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName --create-cert
It give me .pem file, when i try to authenticate from my app it mentioned to me to use the pfx file instead. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: You should be able to convert a pem certificate to pfx.

Comment: it asks for a private key file which I dont have and dont know where to get it from on Azure service principal. any pointer?